# EF.Functions.Like for searching by multiple columns with a search string, that may contains Unicode

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to search by multiple columns with the help of `EF.Functions.Like` function. Here is my example:

```
        public static IQueryable<UserProfile> SearchUserHelper(this IQueryable<UserProfile> userProfileQuery,
            string search)
        {
            
            // Explode string to tokens 
            var searchTokens = Regex.Split(search, "\\s+").ToList();

            var pr  = PredicateBuilder.False<UserProfile>();
            
            foreach (var searchToken in searchTokens)
            {
                pr = pr.Or(e => EF.Functions.Like(e.FirstName, $"%{search}%")
                                || EF.Functions.Like(e.MiddleName, $"%{search}%")
                                || EF.Functions.Like(e.LastName, $"%{search}%")                            
                                || EF.Functions.Like(e.Login, $"%{searchToken}%"));
            }

            userProfileQuery = userProfileQuery.Where(pr);

            return userProfileQuery;
        }
```

As you can see, here is something like helper for searching users in my system. The method takes a search string, explodes it by spaces, and makes new one Where instruction with the help of [predicate builder](https://github.com/lotosbin/BinbinPredicateBuilder).

So, my search request may be like: 'ohn kek' for example. And I know, in the system I have two users: 1) with FirstName = John, 2) with Login = kek. My target is to show the users as the result of the search. With English it works perfect. But other languages give me unexpected result. With other languages, the method just take only the first search substring and ignore the others. What is wrong? Am I miss something?

Comment: Because you're searching in login with searchToken and in Firstname just using search. I expect you have to use searchToken insted of search overall in your search. Another note. What you're doing could be a performance bottleneck. We've had something similar, searched in more fields, and that was a great problem with %searchToken%. searchToken% would speed things up. Also creating a computed column which contains all serchable values would improve performance. On MSSQL it would be also fast to just search for Id's and then do a second search with these ID's.

Comment: Oohhhhh... Thank you!!

Comment: Now I see, the answer is Yes, I miss something) Something big) Now it works!

Comment: @user743414 A computed column? I'm not sure what do you mean. Could you explain more?

Comment: You could start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-computed-column-definition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @user743414 It sounds like you want to do Full Text Search. This is much more efficient than `like '%foo%'`. Unfortunately, FTS is not supported by EF (last I checked). But there are plenty of people who have tried to implement it as an addon. https://github.com/fissoft/Fissoft.EntityFramework.Fts https://thinkrethink.net/2017/06/28/entity-framework-and-full-text-search/

Comment: @Aron Yeah basically we did that. Looks great will take a look at that library.